# Can we use ViewPage in wrap content

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager, android-viewpager2

If I use viewpager in wrap content I always end up with the error

```
Process: com.example.openinapp, PID: 5144

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Pages must fill the whole ViewPager2 (use match_parent)
```

Comment: I think you have added the same link in the "want this" and "currently" part of your question.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In my viewpager adapter making the layout programatically match
   parent will solve this error

//line added

```
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
    return MyViewHolder(view)
}
```

2. Second way is by making match parent in XML

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not too clear, but my suggestion is to give fix width of item, for the viewpager adapter.

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="300dp" //try to give width hardcoded
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/black">
//.....

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Making both match parent will make it working. not fixed